# Unexpected value in Exception object in catch block (c# compact framework)

Tags: c#, exception, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I maintain a c# compact framework application and have had 2 cases in 2 days where the a caught exception had a unexpected string in the Message.  Both times due to a different exception type being thrown.  In the following code the socket exception is caught, but the message shown relates to *something else*.

```
 //method1
 try
 {
     soc.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_serverAddress), _serverPort));

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
 }



 //method2
 try
 {
     m_socServer.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_serverAddress), _serverPort));

 }
 catch (SocketException sex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(sex.Message)
 }
```

In 'method1' the exception is thrown upon fail to connect, the catch block entered, but the message box shown an exception I know is from outside of this try block.  In 'method2' the exception is caught and the message is correct.  These two try catch blocks are the only thing changed in the code.

I have yet to reproduce this in a small test program, but the program I maintain has this behaviour.

Where and why does 'method1' not get the unexpected value?

Comment: From the comments you wrote below I got more confused as to what you really want, I think you need to elaborate on your problem.

Comment: I once worked at a company where someone got fired for excessively using variable names with sexual and sometimes sexist connotation. I got reprimanded for not telling anyone about it. Just him and me worked on it, but he was the senior. I have since chosen to work someplace else. Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably mistaken - in these 2 cases, some other exception (the one you're receiving) is being thrown *instead of* a SocketException.

If you're only expecting SocketException to be thrown, you should only provide a handler for that case.  Other exceptions, in this situation, are probably truly exceptional - meaning that you aren't going to be able to **correctly** recover.

In that case, it's usually better to not handle the exception, and let it bubble up.  If you feel that this is incorrect, put in the SocketException handler AND a generic exception handler, and make sure to check your stack traces (and potentially InnerException properties) in the exceptions:

```
try
{
    //throw SocketException
}
catch (SocketException sockEx)
{
    MessageBox.Show(sockEx.Message)
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
}
```

Comment: I am not mistaken - both examples I have have a ex.Message relating to something outside the try/catch block.

Answer (score 1):

The statement you have above will catch ALL Exceptions, not just a specific type of exception.

If you want to handle specific exception types, you need to have code similar to this:

```
try
{
    // Do some work.
}
catch(SocketException ex)
{
    // Handle a known SocketException
}
catch(NullReferenceException ex)
{
    // Handle a known NullReferenceException
}
catch(OtherSpecificException ex)
{
    // You get the idea
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // This will be everything else you haven't explicitly caught.
    // It will also give you the most generic details about the Exception.
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that it is catching the exception, but the contents of ex.Message is wrong if caught with Excption, if I caught with  SockectExcption everything is fine.

Comment: When you catch the generic Exception, have you checked to make sure the SocketException isn't being wrapped in the InnerException of the one you're catching?

Answer (score 1):

When you handle exceptions you can think of who needs to be notified of the error: the user? or the admin/developer?
You can define that a SocketException contains a message that the user needs to be notified of, and every other exception should be saved for developers or administrators to see. For example you can write the full exception to a file, or event you can have a special MessageBox. "Unexpected Error, please notify the administrator: " + ex.ToString().
Make sure you write the whole ex.ToString() because it includes the stacktrace and all InnerException's.

The best practice is to keep the catch(Exception ex) on the outer level of your application so you handle all unexpected exception in one place.

Comment: I agree, but this does not explain how the 'Exception ex' has unexpected data in the 'Message'

Comment: If all you see is the Message you don't have enough information to understand what the problem is. If you had the exception type and the full stack trace and possible inner exceptions you could more easily understand why an exception occurred.

Comment: The issue is that 'catch (Exception ex)' catches the exception with unexpected (i.e. incorrect) information.  What use is any information if it does not relate to the exception thrown?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by incorrect information. An exception by definition is thrown unexpectedly, usually because of some lack of resources or some bug in the code. You want to have a Catch All somewhere that informs you about all unexpected exceptions so you change your code to deal with it.